# Deserializing JSON with fields that can be of multiple types with Serde

Tags: rust, serde

I have some JSON text data with fields that can be either strings or arrays of strings. Here are four possible examples:

```
{
        "keya": "some string",
        "keyb": "some string"
}


{
        "keya": "some string",
        "keyb": ["some string", "some string"]
}

{
        "keya": ["some string", "some string"],
        "keyb": "some string"
}

{
        "keya": ["some string", "some string"],
        "keyb": ["some string", "some string"]
}
```

How can I create a type that allows me to deserialize such JSON text data using Serde?

Comment: How much of example is this? Could your JSON have *any* structure or is it restricted to the options listed here?

Answer (score 7):

This answer predates the extra requirements given as comments by the OP, but is left as-is as the extra requirements makes it a separate question.

---

**To handle trailing commas**

The input data provided in the question is not valid JSON, due to the existence of trailing commas before every closing bracket `}`. If you *must* work with trailing commas, then the conventional `serde_json` crate doesn't suit your needs, and you may want to replace all usages of `serde_json` with crates supporting trailing commas like [the `json5` crate](https://crates.io/crates/json5). The `json5` provides an API that's similar to `serde_json`, so the following answer is still valid.

**To handle fields that can be of multiple types**

Handling JSON fields with multiple possible value types can be done with an `enum` that holds either a `String` or a `Vec<String>`, with the `#[serde(untagged)]` attribute. See [Enum representations](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) from the official documentation of serde for details about the attribute.

Full example:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum StringOrStringVec {
    String(String),
    Vec(Vec<String>)
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    keya: StringOrStringVec,
    keyb: StringOrStringVec,
}

fn main() {
    let input_json = r#"
        {
            "keya": "some string",
            "keyb": ["some string", "some string"]
        }
    "#;
    let my_obj: MyObj = serde_json::from_str(input_json).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", my_obj);
    
    let input_json = r#"
        {
            "keya": ["some string", "some string"],
            "keyb": "some string"
        }
    "#;
    let my_obj: MyObj = serde_json::from_str(input_json).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", my_obj);
}
```

Example output:

```
MyObj { keya: String("some string"), keyb: Vec(["some string", "some string"]) }
MyObj { keya: Vec(["some string", "some string"]), keyb: String("some string") }
```

[See it in action on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6813c7c77fca0e8ada9c00960413c7eb)

Comment: Hi, the trailing commas were a mistake i've removed them, you might want to edit your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the above .. my problem is that i don't always know what the key name will be - this is GraphQL related

Comment: Then use a `HashMap<String, StringOrStringVec>` or simply a `serde_json::Value` instead of `MyObj` - also, that's a separate question.

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer as-is, since varying key names makes it a different question, which should be asked separately. The enum and attribute part of this answer still applies, and as @Caesar said, using a `HashMap` is a potential solution.

Comment: If i follow the StringOrStringVec example, I then can't iterate over the result when its an array. If i take a row, even when i know it is a Vec<Str> (its graphql so i can check the type) how can i implement to_iter?

Comment: [Use `match` on the enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html) to handle the case where it is a `String` and the case where it is a `Vec<String>`. If you can make sure that a value of type `StringOrStringVec` is of the variant `StringOrStringVec::Vec`, then you may `panic!` on the other `match` arm that can never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

**If you already use** an `either::Either` type you can define "either string or vector of strings" type (eligible for JSON transparent deserialization) like this (https://docs.rs/either/1.10.0/either/serde_untagged/index.html):

### `struct` with inner `Either`

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(transparent)]
struct StringOrVec {
    #[serde(with = "either::serde_untagged")]
    inner: Either<String, Vec<String>>
};
```

Use it like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyObj {
    keya: StringOrVec,
    keyb: StringOrVec,
}
```

The resulting output:

```rust
MyObj { keya: StringOrVec { inner: Left("some string") }, keyb: StringOrVec { inner: Right(["some string", "some string"]) } }
MyObj { keya: StringOrVec { inner: Right(["some string", "some string"]) }, keyb: StringOrVec { inner: Left("some string") } }
```

### `enum StringOrVec`

Using `Either` is less convenient than the `enum` from the answer of [@kotatsuyaki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74615799/10795361).
That's why, I still **prefer** defining the type via `enum` like this:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum StringOrVec {
    String(String),
    Vec(Vec<String>)
}
```

Output:

```rust
MyObj { keya: String("some string"), keyb: Vec(["some string", "some string"]) }
MyObj { keya: Vec(["some string", "some string"]), keyb: String("some string") }
```