# Serde: how to deal with unpredictable JSON results

Tags: rust, serde

This relates to my earlier question:
[Deserializing JSON with fields that can be of multiple types with Serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615731/deserializing-json-with-fields-that-can-be-of-multiple-types-with-serde?noredirect=1#comment131708955_74615731)

It was suggested i start a new question.

In order to deserialise results where i could have either a HashMap<String, String> or a Hashmap <String, Vec>. I use:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum StringOrStringVec {
    String(String),
    Vec(Vec<String>)
}
```

and to parse the json:

```
    let deserialized: HashMap<String, StringOrStringVec> = serde_json::from_str(&msg.as_str().unwrap()).unwrap();
```

But how do i now call to_iter to iterate over a <String, Vec> result?
If i try to do this, none of the traits needed are available out of the box.

Do i really need to create them?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is convert all of the `StringOrStringVec`s to just `Vec<String>`s:

```rust
let deserialized: HashMap<String, StringOrStringVec> = serde_json::from_str(&msg.as_str().unwrap()).unwrap();

let deserialized: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = deserialized.into_iter().map(|(key, val)| match val {
    StringOrStringVec::String(s) => (key, vec![s]),
    StringOrStringVec::Vec(v) => (key, v),
}).collect();
```

Then it will be easier to work with.

Comment: this is so brilliant it made me giggle ... thanks so much, hadnt thought for a second to do something so incredibly smart and simple! im still keen to see what other options there are so im just going to plus one this for now. Thanks again