# Variant types in JSON5 (serde)

Tags: rust, serde, json5

I am wondering how one could support a "type-fluid" (aka variant type) field in JSON when mapped via serde. As parser, I am using `json5` crate (backed by `serde`). And certain input fields might contain key-values which are either `"foo": "bar"` or a list behind the same key, i.e. `"foo": [ "bar", "and", "more" ]`.

And the documentation of https://serde.rs/data-model.html does not actually give me a clue on how to map this usecase. I tried using an enum as variant carrier, see below, but that does not work, and at runtime this ends up in some error result like `` Err(Message { msg: "unknown variant `hello world`, expected `Single` or `Multi`", location: Some(Location { line: 4, column: 20 }) }) ``.

So far I still don't see a way to tell it "take this either as value or as list of values and let me see which kind you have parsed".

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum StringOrStrings {
    Single(String),
    Multi(Vec<String>),
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Config {
    message: StringOrStrings,
    n: i32,
}
```

Comment: You can find all the answers here: https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an untagged enum as the other answer explains, which allows you to deserialize one out of a few options, trying each in order until one succeeds.

However, you can generalize this solution even further to handle *any* deserializable data type (not just strings), as well as hide the "maybe `Vec`" detail by wrapping a single value in a `Vec` like this:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Config {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deser_maybe_vec")]
    message: Vec<String>,
    n: i32,
}

fn deser_maybe_vec<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum SingleOrVec<T> {
        Single(T),
        Vec(Vec<T>),
    }

    Ok(match SingleOrVec::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        SingleOrVec::Single(v) => vec![v],
        SingleOrVec::Vec(v) => v,
    })
}
```

Note that if you need to derive `Serialize` on `Config` you don't need to handle that case specially using `serialize_with` because the default implementation will produce a sequence containing one item, which is a valid representation of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
Basically the same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615731/deserializing-json-with-fields-that-can-be-of-multiple-types-with-serde)

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b8fc73e83d04aa7b8cac2a142f430fed)

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::Value;


#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum StringOrStringVec {
    String(String),
    Vec(Vec<String>)
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Config {
    message: StringOrStringVec,
    n: i32,
}

fn main (){
    let json_string = r#"
        {
            "message": "hello",
            "n": 42
        }
    "#;

    let json_vec = r#"
        {
            "message": ["hello", "world"],
            "n": 42
        }
    "#;

    let my_obj: Config = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", my_obj);
    
    let my_obj: Config = serde_json::from_str(json_vec).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", my_obj);
}
```

Comment: Note `extern crate` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Both are good answers but the one from @cdhowie goes already a step ahead and saves me from tedious type deduction later.